# Laravel - Chaining hasOne->belongsTo Relationship in Eloquent

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have the following schema

```
CoinTransaction
    -id
    -name
    -paper_transaction_id
PaperTransaction
    -id
    -name
    -paper_product_id
PaperProduct
    -id
    -name
```

`CoinTransaction` and `PaperTransaction` has a 1 to 1 relationship through `CoinTransaction.paper_transaction_id` = `PaperTransaction.id`.  `PaperTransaction` and `PaperProduct` has a many to one relationship through `PaperTransaction.paper_product_id` to `PaperProduct.id`.

I can connect `CoinTransaction` and `PaperTransaction` together in the `CoinTransaction` model using

```
    public function paperTransactions(){

        return $this->hasOne('PaperTransaction', 'id', 'paper_transaction_id');

    }
```

I've tried connecting all three together using

```
public function paperProducts(){

    $paperTransactions = $this->hasOne('PaperTransaction', 'id', 'paper_transaction_id');
    return $paperTransactions->getResults()->belongsTo('PaperProduct', 'paper_product_id');

}
```

But this returns no data related to `PaperTransaction` or `PaperProduct`.

Is there a way to chain the built-in Eloquent methods to get what I am looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using a nested relationship, for example, in your `CoinTransaction` model use the following:

```
public function paperTransaction()
{
    return $this->hasOne('PaperTransaction', 'paper_transaction_id');
}
```

In your `PaperTransaction` model use the following:

```
public function paperProduct()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('PaperProduct', 'paper_product_id');
}
```

So now, you'll be able to query with relation using something like the following:

```
$coinTransaction = CoinTransaction::with('paperTransaction.paperProduct')->get();
```

So if you want to access the related model then you can do it like this way:

```
$paperTransaction = $coinTransaction->paperTransaction->toArray(); // or a field
$paperProduct = $coinTransaction->paperTransaction->paperProduct->toArray(); // or a field
```